# Unexpected results from setfacl on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: permissions

I tried using setfacl on Ubuntu 18.04, but i got unexpected results. In the  simple example here there is a directory: home, 2 users: me, she and a group consisting of these two users.
The filesystem is mounted with acl enabled, i checked this with tune2fs.

Here is a part of the script i use to set permissions:

```
#remove all chmod perms
chmod -R u=,g=,o=   home
# remove default acl settings
setfacl -R -b -k    home
# set default acl 
setfacl -dR -m u:me:rwx,g:we:rwx home
# set actual permissions
setfacl -R -m u:me:rwx,g:we:rwx home

ls -al home
d---rwx---+  9 me    we  4096 sep  5 18:36 .
d---rwx---+  8 me    we  4096 sep  4 15:27 energy
d---rws---+ 13 she   we  4096 sep  4 15:26 she

# Very strange , the chmod group bits are set!
# setfacl should not touch these bits?

# check acl bits
getfacl home

# getfacl output
# file: home
# owner: me
# group: we
user::---
user:me:rwx
group::---
group:we:rwx
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::---
default:user:me:rwx
default:group::---
default:group:we:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---

# as expected

# run as user: me
ls home
# result of: ls home:
Permission denied

# Although the acl bits are ok, permission denied!
# It looks like the system api does not use acl bits
```

Questions:

1 Are the standard chmod bits different from the acl bits?

2 Why does setfacl modify the chmod group bits?

Whenever i run: setfacl -R -m u:someuser:rw directory

the chmod group bits are set.

3 The aclbits are set to allow access but access is still denied, why?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found some complete doc explaining the details.
I used the setfacl command in the wrong way: when setting acls for owing user and owing group the command is:

```
setfacl -R -m u::rwX,g::rwX dir
```

The syntax with an explicit user and/or group is when acls are being used for non-owing principals. Most examples on the internet handles about these cases, not very instructive.
This acl mechanism is apparently based on a Posix draft that never made it.
I think this mechanism does not fit very wel in the existing unix permissions system.